# MS Project Tapping emails

Tags: email, project

As a start I want to find a way of being able to select one or more UIDs and generate an email advising the assigned resource to commence the tasks.
The email would have a defined template.

Can this be done with macros and VB?

Is it also possible to them update a custom field at the same time against all the included UiDs with a value TAPPED and colour the row/s?

I haven't tried j7zt looking at options